# Identifying the context of word in sentence

Tags: nlp, data-mining, nltk, semantics

I created classifier to classy the class of nouns,adjectives, Named entities in given sentence. I have used large Wikipedia dataset for classification.

Like :

Where Abraham Lincoln was born?

So classifier will give this short of result - `word - class`

- Where  - question
- Abraham Lincoln - Person, Movie, Book (because    classifier find Abraham Lincoln in all there categories)
- born - time

When Titanic was released?

- when - question
- Titanic - Song, movie, Vehicle, Game (Titanic
  classified in all these categories)

**Is there any way to identify exact context for word?**

Please see :

1. Word sense disambiguation would not help here. Because there might not be near by word in sentence which can help
2. Lesk algorithm with wordnet or sysnet also does not help. Because it for suppose word `Bank` lesk algo will behave like this

   ======== TESTING simple_lesk ===========

   ## TESTING simple_lesk() ...

   Context: I went to the bank to deposit my money

   Sense: Synset('depository_financial_institution.n.01')

   Definition: a financial institution that accepts deposits and channels the money into lending activities

   ## TESTING simple_lesk() with POS ...

   Context: The river bank was full of dead fishes

   Sense: Synset('bank.n.01')

   Definition: sloping land (especially the slope beside a body of water)

Here for word `bank` it suggested as `financial institute` and `slopping land`. While in my case I am already getting such prediction like `Titanic` then it can be `movie` or `game`.

I want to know is there any other approach apart from `Lesk algo`, `baseline algo`, `traditional word sense disambiguation` which can help me to identify which class is correct for particular keyword?

Titanic -

Comment: If, in the first example "born" is to be classified as "time", why does "release" in the second example not receive any classification?

Comment: @ChthonicProject: thanks for your comment. The reason behind this is feature based classification system. Time class has been trained using entities contexually expressing time like `when , how long, duration, born` and so on. It's not enough intelligent to identify `released` as time based event. Semi superwise and unsuperwised learning system might have identified it

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for using the `pywsd` [examples](https://github.com/alvations/pywsd). With regards to wsd, there are many other variants and i'm coding them by myself during my free time. So if you want to see it improve do join me in coding the open source tool =)

Meanwhile, you will find the following technologies more relevant to your task, such as:

- **Knowledge base population** (http://www.nist.gov/tac/2014/KBP/) where tokens/segments of text are assigned an entity and the task is to link them or to solve a simplified question and answer task.
- **Knowledge representation** (http://groups.csail.mit.edu/medg/ftp/psz/k-rep.html)
- **Knowledge extraction** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_extraction)

The above technologies usually includes several sub-tasks such as:

- Wikification (http://nlp.cs.rpi.edu/kbp/2014/elreading.html)
- Entity linking
- Slot filling (http://surdeanu.info/kbp2014/def.php)

**Essentially you're asking for a tool that is an NP-complete AI system for language/text processing, so I don't really think such a tool exists as of yet. Maybe it's IBM Watson.**

if you're looking for the field to look into, the field is out there but if you're looking at tools, most probably wikification tools are closest to what you might need. (http://nlp.cs.rpi.edu/paper/WikificationProposal.pdf)